# Differentiating with respect to a product of two variables

Tags: derivatives

I want to differentiate a function $C(h,u)$ associated with [Manning friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manning_formula):

$$
C(h,u) = h^{-1/3} u \lvert u \rvert
$$

According to WolframAlpha, $\mathrm{d} C / \mathrm{d} (hu)$ is
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}(hu)} h^{-1/3}u\lvert u \rvert = h^{-4/3} \lvert u \rvert
$$

But how is this derivative calculated?